# selenium java try to access database through vpn

Tags: java, jdbc, jsch

I try to verify total comment between frontend and database result. since the database can only accessed through VPN, it makes me stuck. I been tried with below code, but the result is empty, the only ssh connected in the console

```
public class ConnectDB {

private static Connection connection = null;
private static Session session = null;


private static void connectToServer(String dataBaseName) throws SQLException {
    connectSSH();
    connectToDataBase(dataBaseName);
}

public static void connectSSH() throws SQLException {
    String sshHost = "my ssh host";
    String sshuser = "my ssh user";
    String dbuserName = "username db";
    String dbpassword = "pass db";
    String SshKeyFilepath = "/Users/mac/.ssh/id_rsa";

    int localPort = 8740; // any free port can be used
    String remoteHost = "ip db";
    int remotePort = 3306;
    String localSSHUrl = "localhost";
    /***************/
    String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

    try {
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        session = jsch.getSession(sshuser, sshHost, 22);
        jsch.addIdentity(SshKeyFilepath);
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        config.put("ConnectionAttempts", "3");
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();

        System.out.println("SSH Connected");

        Class.forName(driverName).newInstance();

        int assinged_port = session.setPortForwardingL(localPort, remoteHost, remotePort);

        System.out.println("localhost" + assinged_port + " -> " + remoteHost + ":" + remotePort);
        System.out.println("Port Forwarded");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void connectToDataBase(String dataBaseName) throws SQLException {
    String dbuserName = "username db";
    String dbpassword = "pass db";
    int localPort = 8740; // any free port can be used
    String localSSHUrl = "ip db"; //since ssh connected i guess to put ip db
    try {

        //mysql database connectivity
        MysqlDataSource dataSource = new MysqlDataSource();
        dataSource.setServerName(localSSHUrl);
        //dataSource.setPortNumber(localPort);
        dataSource.setUser(dbuserName);
        dataSource.setAllowMultiQueries(true);

        dataSource.setPassword(dbpassword);
        dataSource.setDatabaseName(dataBaseName);

        connection = dataSource.getConnection();

        System.out.print("Connection to server successful!:" + connection + "\n\n");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public static void closeConnections() {
    CloseDataBaseConnection();
    CloseSSHConnection();
}

public static void CloseDataBaseConnection() {
    try {
        if (connection != null && !connection.isClosed()) {
            System.out.println("Closing Database Connection");
            connection.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static void CloseSSHConnection() {
    if (session != null && session.isConnected()) {
        System.out.println("Closing SSH Connection");
        session.disconnect();
    }
}


// works ONLY FOR  single query (one SELECT or one DELETE etc)
public static ResultSet executeMyQuery(String query, String dataBaseName) {
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    try {
        connectToServer(dataBaseName);
        Statement stmt = (Statement) connection.createStatement();
        resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        System.out.println("Database connection success");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return resultSet;
}

public static void DeleteOrganisationReferencesFromDB(String organisationsLike) {
    try {
        connectToServer("ServerName");
        Statement stmt = (Statement) connection.createStatement();

        ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery("select * from DB1");

        String organisationsToDelete = "";
        List<String> organisationsIds = new ArrayList<String>();

        // create string with id`s values to delete organisations references
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            String actualValue = resultSet.getString("id");
            organisationsIds.add(actualValue);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < organisationsIds.size(); i++) {
            organisationsToDelete = " " + organisationsToDelete + organisationsIds.get(i);
            if (i != organisationsIds.size() - 1) {
                organisationsToDelete = organisationsToDelete + ", ";
            }
        }

        stmt.executeUpdate(" DELETE FROM `DB1`.`table1` WHERE `DB1`.`table1`.`organisation_id` in ( " + organisationsToDelete + " );");


    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        closeConnections();
    }
}

public static List<String> getOrganisationsDBNamesBySubdomain(String organisationsLike) {
    List<String> organisationDbNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    ResultSet resultSet = executeMyQuery("select `DB`.organisation.dbname from `DB1`.organisation where subdomain like '" + organisationsLike + "%'", "DB1");
    try {
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            String actualValue = resultSet.getString("dbname");
            organisationDbNames.add(actualValue);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        closeConnections();
    }
    return organisationDbNames;
}

 public static List<String> getAllDBNames() {
    // get all live db names incentral DB
    List<String> organisationDbNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    ResultSet resultSet = executeMyQuery("show databases", "DB1");
    try {
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            String actualValue = resultSet.getString("Database");
            organisationDbNames.add(actualValue);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        closeConnections();
    }
    return organisationDbNames;
}

  public static void deleteDataBasesByName(List<String> DataBasesNamesList) {
    try {
        connectSSH();
        int dataBasesAmount = DataBasesNamesList.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < dataBasesAmount; i++) {
            connectToDataBase(DataBasesNamesList.get(i));

            Statement stmt = (Statement) connection.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate("DROP database `" + DataBasesNamesList.get(i) + "`");

        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        CloseDataBaseConnection();
        closeConnections();
    }
}
```

but the result in console, no sign that query is executed
*the query is on another file

```
conn.connectSSH();
conn.executeMyQuery("select shade_item FROM nubr_product_shade WHERE shade_id=1", "database_name");
```

SSH Connected
localhost8740 -> 172.xx.x.xx:3306
Port Forwarded

Comment: Please post [mcve] => Most of the code in your question is not needed to show the problem. Show us a simple block of code (no methods) that opens a tunnel and tries to execute a single query. + You should also better describe what problem does your current code have. *"no sign that query is executed"* is pretty vague.

Answer (score 0):

Why you not do that with operating system utils ?
for example (MySQL Database) :

```
ssh -R 3306:127.0.0.1:3306 username@server.com -NnT
```

now jdbc connection to localhost with port 3306 .

Comment: its not working, on console proccess always loading until timeout